# Interop userControl c# into vb6 program

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, vb6, com-interop

I have problems when I want to use my usercontrol created a staff of interop user control in c#. I can register it with the tool of the framework regasm lib.dll codebase.

regasm xxxx.dll /Codebase /tlb:xxxx.tlb

But when i add my dll in component o reference project i have a problem , the ide Vb6 launch me this error or warning

The file  was not registerable as an ActiveX Component.

can you help me?

thanks

Comment: C# libraries are not like VB6 ActiveX libraries. If you're writing a library or control in C#, then you should be using C# to create your UI to use it. My recommendation: do NOT develop anything in VB6 any more.

Comment: I need  my usercontrol c# interop for a ERP UI made into vb6

Comment: Seriously, don't. Just don't. Make your UI/libraries in VB6, OR C#. You can theoretically still use VB6 libraries in new C# front end UIs although the use case for this is fairly slim, but don't even consider it in the other direction (i.e. VB6 UI - C# libraries). Do it all in VB6, or all in C#. Seriously.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.The question if I have a component made ​​in vb6 ocx which is a virtual keyboard on the screen.
When I click on a button you should take the focus where a textbox is located.
I need the control from running in a separate thread.
And I can not accomplish!

Comment: My code in vb6 [codeVb](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=7F3C9E2F5E23C353!3085&authkey=!AFfoGunshTFJkKA&ithint=file%2crar)